# Permission denied error in xcode 8

Tags: xcode

I have added Fabric framework into my project manually before, and then deleted. This error showed up at the compile time:

> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-hityylzihqrkrscmfhbjcpmsmbhv/Build/Intermediates/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.build/Script-*****************************.sh: line 2: ./Fabric.framework/run: Permission denied

Comment: Your question needs to be edited. What do you seek to achieve and what did you tried in order to resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Post the code you have tried. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the execute flag on that script has been lost.  Go to the command line and do:

```
$ cd /path/to/project/path/to/Fabric.framework
$ chmod 0755 run
```